# How can i transfer info recyclerview to another recyclerview and back

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How can i transfer data one recyclerview to other recyclerview an activity and back. 
When  click one recylerview element it is showing another recyclerview and invisible clicked recyclerview element and opposite this prosess
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqplv.png)

Comment: On select  of first recyclerview Item. find the object by position, and Copy it the list o f second recyclerview arrayList. and notify the adapter

Comment: Hi Elsen, 
If you want a good answer, I recommend you to do a better question. Edit it, and tell us, what did you try, what data do you want to transfer and "when"... etc..

Take a look to -->https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Shudy thanks. in image i describe but i can't write detail info because my English is bad

Comment: @Elsen Almasli check this link. https://sunny89blog.wordpress.com/2017/07/16/transfer-items-from-one-recyclerview-to-another-and-vice-versa/

Answer (score 0):

simply remove item by using notifyitemremoved(pogition);
to first list of adapter and copy the item content.

then insert item to another recyclerview list adapter by 
notifyiteminserted();

hope this will solve your problem;

Comment: https://medium.com/@studymongolian/updating-data-in-an-android-recyclerview-842e56adbfd8